# Can a Smart App banner launch an app installed from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to prototype the integration between a Smart App Banner and an iOS app. Is it possible for a Smart App Banner to launch an iOS app that was installed from Xcode instead of the App Store (on either a device or in the simulator)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible. Only App Store apps can be launched by a Smart App Banner.

Comment: Install app from AppStore then build app with Xcode without uninstall, then smart app banner will work on your debug app

Comment: How about testing that deep linking work correctly then ? I need to send the app to the AppStore hoping it will work the first time ?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, not for an app that has no listing on the App Store.

The smart app banner 'code' requires the app id from the App Store, which is not available from an app just installed from Xcode.

If the app is an update to an existing app that you've installed via Xcode, then as long as it's available on the iTunes store it will launch the app as far as I am aware.

Comment: My app does have a listing in the App Store but the App Store version doesn't yet have the hooks to handle the URLs passed from the banner. I'd like the banner to open the version I install from Xcode instead of the App Store version.

Comment: Are you not seeing that behaviour?

Comment: Correct. If the App Store version is installed, it will be launched. If not, it will open the App Store. There is no way, as far as I can tell, to have it open a build you've loaded from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1. I installed the app from the AppStore using a device running iOS 6.
2. then I overwrote it with a dev build using Xcode 6.

The only hard part is to get an iOS 6 device.